# How do I remove clearfix from woocommerce shortcutcode

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, clearfix

I am using wordpress and I just pasted woocommerce products shortcut code.
So, I want to know how do I remove clearfix div from woocommerce shortcutcode or HTML, any ideas?
As you can see the screenshot (Sorry have keep it hidden for some reasons)
That after the first div there is the clearfix, which drops the other 2 div.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a product or something useful inside crearfix div ?

Comment: No, the products are in div's called "col-md-3". I just pasted the shortcut code and that div comes automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to solve it by adding display:none to that div in WP css but you should use some really specific selector to affect only that single div.
You can try something like this

```
.woocommerce.columns-3>.clearfix.clear>clearfix {
    display:none; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually worked out! Appreciated! Good day! :)